# How do I configure the number of worker threads used by SqlServer 2005 Agent

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server

How can I increase the limit of worker threads from the default 10 for SQL Server 2005 SqlAgent?  I have 9 jobs that run almost continuously and that leaves only one available thread for the rest of the scheduled jobs.  Oftentimes, when no thread is available, I will see the jobs in "Waiting for worker thread" state.  I'd like to increase the number to about 12 (which should do the trick for me).  Any idea where this is set?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306457) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to update the [syssubsystems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174368.aspx) table directly in msdb.
The default `max_worker_theads` is set to 80 (for the t-sql subsystem), which sounds like it should be more then enough.